# possible to add storyboard to non storyboard project?

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

I am new to Objective C, but with experience of C#.  I have a project named "chat secure" (on github), but I don't know how the project works without storyboard.  I would like to add storyboard to the project. Is it possible to use Storyboard along with other project?

Comment: Add new storyboard to the project by File->New->File...->Userinterface->storyboard
And then, you must drag and drop a ViewController or anything same as.
On ViewController, you must link it to a Class

Comment: yes, when i do it, i just got a whole black screen?

Comment: check isInitialViewController in storyBoard

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
ShopObject *obj = arrDeals[indexPath.section];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SwipeDealViewSB" bundle: nil];
StoryBoardViewController *swipeDealViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryBoardViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:swipeDealViewController animated:YES];
```

But remember to name your storyboard identify and custom class is"StoryBoardViewController" [demonstrate image to identify storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmBj3.png)